# Calculate $\int^3_{0}\frac{-x^2}{4}+5dx$ by using the definition $\int^b_{a}f(x)dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}[ \overset{n} \sum_{i = 1} f(x_{i})\Delta x]$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

I am trying to calculate $\int^3_{0}\frac{-x^2}{4}+5dx$ by using the definition $\int^b_{a}f(x)dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}[ \overset{n} \sum_{i = 1}  f(x_{i})\Delta x]$.

**The full question text is:**

> consider the function $f(x)= - \frac{x^2}{4}+5$ by using the definition
>
> $$\int^b_{a}f(x)dx=\lim_{n \to \infty}[ \overset{n} \sum_{i = 1}  f(x_{i})\Delta x]$$
>
> The summation inside the brackets is $R_{n}$ which is the Riemann sum where the sample points are chosen to be the right-hand endpoints of each sub-interval.
>
> Calculate $R_{n}$ for $f(x)= -\frac{x^2}{4}+5$ on the interval $[0, 3]$ and write your answer as a function of $n$ without any summation signs. You will need the summation formulas
>
> $$\overset{n}\sum_{i = 1} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
>
> $$\overset{n}\sum_{i = 1} i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
>
> $R_n=$ ?
>
> $\lim_{n \to \infty} R_n=$ ?

I am not sure why they are giving me the summation formulas here.

I thought problems like this were solved by finding $\Delta x$ and then using that to find $x_{i}$.

Then I would plug in $x_{i}$ to the formula $\lim_{n \to \infty}[ \overset{n} \sum_{i = 1}  f(x_{i})\Delta x]$, and simplify.

It seems like to use the summation formulas mentioned, I would need to get everything but maybe $x_{i}$ to the left the $\sum$ symbol, but I'm not sure how, or if that's what I'm supposed to do.

Since $\Delta x = \frac{b-a}{n}=\frac{3}{n}$ and $x_i = a - \Delta x_i = \frac{3_i}{n}$

I thought the answer would come from $\lim_{n \to \infty}[ \overset{n} \sum_{i = 1}  (\frac{3_i}{n})\frac{3}{n}]$, but I'm not sure what else I can do with this, and I don't know what form of answer the question is asking for.

Comment: You have to plug your $x_i$ (which by the way are correct) into $f$!

Comment: @b00nheT I thought I did that when I did $\lim_{n \to \infty}[ \overset{n} \sum_{i = 1}  (\frac{3_i}{n})\frac{3}{n}]$

Comment: @b00nheT Oh! Do you mean like this, $\lim_{n \to \infty}\overset{n}\sum_{i = 1} (-\frac{(\frac{3_i}{n})^2 }{4}+5)(\frac{3}{n})$?

Comment: @LuinousNutria. Exactly! See Peter's answer for the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the definition given you have
$$f(x_i)=f\left(\frac{3i}n\right)=-\frac{9i^2}{4n^2}+5$$
$$\Delta x=\frac3n$$
Hence the integral is given by
$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\left(-\frac{9i^2}{4n^2}+5\right)\frac3n\right)
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\left(-\frac{27i^2}{4n^3}+\frac{15}n\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\frac{27}{4n^3}\sum_{i=1}^ni^2+\frac{15}n\sum_{i=1}^n 1\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\frac{27}{4n^3}\left(\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6\right)+\frac{15}n(n)\right)\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(-\frac{27}{4}\left(\frac{(1+\frac1n)(2+\frac1n)}6\right)+15\right)\\
&=-\frac{27}4\left(\frac26\right)+15\\
&=-\frac94+15\\
&=\frac{51}4\\
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

You seem to have all the elements. By linearity, you have to determine
\begin{cases}\displaystyle \sum _{i=1}^n x_i^2\,\Delta x = \sum _{i=1}^n \Bigl(\frac{3i}{n}\Bigr)^2\frac 3n=\frac{27}{n^3}\sum _{i=1}^n i^2,\\[1ex]
\displaystyle\sum _{i=1}^n 1\,\Delta x=3.
\end{cases}
Can you continue?